# Sum rows based on columns inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sum

I am quite new to pandas, but I use python at a good level.

I have a pandas dataframe which is organized as follows

```
idrun    idbasin    time    q
-192540      1        0     0
-192540      1        1     0.5
...
-192540      2        0     0
-192540      2        1     1
...
-192540      3        0     0
-192540      3        1     1
...
-192541      1        0     0
-192541      1        1     0.5
...
-192541      2        0     0
-192541      2        1     1
...
-192541      3        0     0
-192541      3        1     1
...
```

It is a fairly large dataframe (7 columns and ~600k rows).

What I would like to do is: given a tuple containing values referring to the `idbasin` column (e.g. `(1,2)`), if the `idrun` value is the same

1. sum the `q` column of the referred `idbasin` values, i.e. for the example it would be `(1,2)`
2. remove the rows corresponding to that `idrun` value and the tuple-specified `idbasin` values
3. insert the summed values with `idbasin` equal to the first number of the tuple.

Referring to my example df, the results would be

```
idrun    idbasin    time    q
-192540      1        0     0
-192540      1        1     1.5
...
-192540      3        0     0
-192540      3        1     1
...
-192541      1        0     0
-192541      1        1     1.5
...
-192541      3        0     0
-192541      3        1     1
...
```

My solution would to use `groupby` to turn the `df` to a `dict` and then do the operation with one or two for loops, but I understand that iterating in pandas is not the optimal solution, so I believe there could be a "pandas" solution using the `df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace values of tuple by first value of tuple in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
tup = (1, 2)

df['idbasin'] = df['idbasin'].mask(df['idbasin'].isin(tup), tup[0])
#alternative
#df['idbasin'] = np.where(df['idbasin'].isin(tup), tup[0], df['idbasin'])
df = df.groupby(['idrun', 'idbasin','time'], as_index=False)['q'].sum()
print (df)
    idrun  idbasin  time    q
0 -192541        1     0  0.0
1 -192541        1     1  1.5
2 -192541        3     0  0.0
3 -192541        3     1  1.0
4 -192540        1     0  0.0
5 -192540        1     1  1.5
6 -192540        3     0  0.0
7 -192540        3     1  1.0
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks!